# Game Object working in scene and game view, but completely invisible in Android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, invisible, gameobject

I have thoroughly searched on the web but I couldn't find anyone with my same problem.

I'm working on a 3D game for Android using Unity. Everything works fine within the editor and on the Unity Remote app, but when I build the project, install it on my smartphone and start it... I can't see a game object.

A screen of the project:

[image]

As you can see, the sword is active and visible in the editor, but once I start the actual build I get this:

[image]

I can't understand what's wrong, could someone kindly help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I upgraded from Unity 5.3.2 to 5.3.4, re-built the project and everything works like a charm now.

Sometimes Unity can be... strange.

Answer (score 0):

Does the material of the sword have the standart shader?
If so try one of the mobile ones.

Another idea would be to upgrade to one of the newer p versions of Unity.

Comment: Would this be considered an answer or a comment?

Comment: Acutually it's both, so I didnt know where to put it. To upgrade unity often helped me and other people too, so thats my answer.

Comment: Changing the shader didn't solve the problem... I'll try upgrading Unity to 5.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Since the sword has a rigidbody, have you enabled gravity and somehow disabled collision and its falling through the ground?

Other than that, it could be a shader problem.

Comment: I haven't enabled gravity and everything works correctly in the editor preview.

I also think it has something to do with shaders, but I've tried mobile ones and nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Unity? I had some shader errors awhile back, and it was fine once I upgraded.